# Should the deallocate function be called when an error occurs in the STL allocator allocate?

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

```
            try
            {
                node = allocator.allocate(LIST_BASIC_UNIT);
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                allocator.deallocate(node);
                throw;
            }
```

Should I call deallocator when an exception occurs in the STL allocator allocate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot deallocate anything, because there is nothing to deallocate. If `allocate()` throws, then it stops before it could return a pointer and before `node` could have any value assigned. So assuming that `node` is invalid before `try` block (it should be), you have no valid pointer to pass to `deallocate()`.

If given implementation of allocator fails to guarantee no change when exception is thrown, that's a fault in this allocator, not in your container.